# Loop through data set until specific point - Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop, dataset, infinite-loop

I've run an experiment where a machine exerts a force on a bridge until it breaks. I need to cycle through my entire data set and calculate the toughness until I've hit the breaking point (fdValue1).
The toughness is calculated by summing up all the rectangles under my load vs. distance curve. (Basically the integral) 
However, I have not been able to find a reasonable way of doing so and my current loop is an infinite loop and I'm not sure why.

```
  %Initializing variables
  bridge1Data = xlsread('Bridge1Data.xlsx', 'A2:C2971');
  bridge2Data = xlsread('Bridge2Data.xlsx', 'A2:C1440');

  bridge1Load = bridge1Data(:, 2);
  bridge2Load = bridge2Data(:, 2);

  bridge1Dist = bridge1Data(:, 3);
  bridge2Dist = bridge2Data(:, 3);

  [row1, col1] = size(bridge1Dist);
  [row2, col2] = size(bridge2Dist);

  bridge1Disp = zeros(row1, col1);
  bridge2Disp = zeros(row2, col2);

  fdValue1 = 0.000407350000000029;

  &Main code
  %Displacement
  for k = 2:length(bridge1Dist)
      bridge1Disp(k-1, 1) = bridge1Dist(k, 1) - bridge1Dist(k-1, 1);
  end

  %Max Load Bridge 1
  maxLoad1 = 0;
  for n = 1:length(bridge1Load)
      for k = 1
          if bridge1Load(n, k) > maxLoad1
              maxLoad1 = bridge1Load(n, k);
          end
      end
  end

  %Cycle through data till failure, change proj data
  totalRect1 = 0;
  for j = 2:length(bridge1Disp) 
      while bridge1Disp(j, 1) ~= fdValue1
          rectangle = (bridge1Disp(j, 1) - bridge1Disp(j-1, 1))*...
                      ((bridge1Load(j, 1) + bridge1Load(j-1, 1))/2);
          totalRect1 = totalRect1 + rectangle;
      end
  end
```

Basically, I make an array for the load and distance the machine pushes down on the bridge, assign a 'Failure Distance' value (fdValue) which should be used to determine when we stop calculating toughness. I then calculate displacement, calculate the maximum load. Then through the variable 'rectangle', calculate each rectangle and sum them all up in 'totalRect1', and use that to calculate the toughness by finding the area under the curve. Is anyone able to see why the loop is an infinite loop?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the condition `while bridge1Disp(j, 1) ~= fdValue1` is that you need to check for `<=` and not for (in)equality, since `double` numbers will almost never evaluate to be equal even if they seem so. To read more about this you can look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html#bt2klek-3) and also [google for *matlab double comparison*](https://www.google.com/search?q=matlab%20double%20comparison). Generally it has something to do with precision issues.

Usually when checking for double **equality** you should use something like `if abs(val-TARGET)<1E-4`, and specify some tolerance which you are willing to permit.

---

Regardless,

You don't need to use loops for what you're trying to do. I'm guessing this comes from some `C`-programming habits, which are not required in MATLAB.

The 1st loop (*`Displacement`*), which computes the difference between every two adjacent elements can be replaced by the function [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) like so:

```
bridge1Disp = diff(bridge1Dist);
```

The 2nd loop construct (*`Max Load Bridge 1`*), which retrieves the maximum element of `bridge1Load` can be replaced by the command [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) as follows:

```
maxLoad1 = max(bridge1Load);
```

For the last loop construct (*`Cycle ...`*) consider the functions I've mentioned above, and also [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html).

Comment: Hey @Dev-iL, the tips regarding max and diff are really useful and I actually know they're more efficient. However, this is an assignment where we're forced to use loops (very annoying).
I've reformatted the statement as follows
`for j = 2:length(bridge1Disp) 
    ....stuff
    if bridge1Disp{j, 1} == fdValue1
       break;
    end
end`
However, I get: Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Comment: @AnasYousef No no.... Like I said, testing for equality should be done using `if abs(val-TARGET)<1E-4` **NOT** `==`. And in any case, you need to set it to `<=`. Why did you change it to cells all of a sudden (`{}`)? And lastly, since `bridge1Dist` is a vector, you don't need a 2nd subscript to access its elements - that's just confusing (use `bridge1Disp(j)`).

Comment: My bad, I changed to ( {} ) because I got an error using my method. Just tried yours and it looped through successfully. Thanks! Time to debug the rest of this....

Answer (score 0):

In the code section

```
%Cycle through data till failure, change proj data
totalRect1 = 0;
for j = 2:length(bridge1Disp)
   while bridge1Disp(j, 1) ~= fdValue1
      rectangle = (bridge1Disp(j, 1) - bridge1Disp(j-1, 1))*...
         ((bridge1Load(j, 1) + bridge1Load(j-1, 1))/2);
      totalRect1 = totalRect1 + rectangle;
   end
end
```

the test condition of the `while` loop is

```
bridge1Disp(j, 1) ~= fdValue1
```

nevertheless, in the `while` loop the value of `bridge1Disp(j, 1)` does not change so if at the first iteratiion of the while loop `bridge1Disp(j, 1)` is `~= fdValue1` the loop will never end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've added a break as a replacement to the while loop in the for loop section (see comment below). But this time I get: Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.